# How to stop .bat execution by pressing any key?

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to know how to stop a .bat by pressing any key.

I dont want using Ctrl+C, Is there any .bat command to stop a running loop command by pressing any key?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  **:-)** Does it *have to be*  a keypress or is another BAT stopping the first BAT good enough?  If that's the case, leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: I mean that if touch any key the whole bat stops

Comment: The BAT file has to be completely rewritten checking for keypresses in-between commands and will only stop if the next command is executed, not if a command itself is executed.  *Possible but I'd like to know:* why are you trying to do this (It might be a *bad idea*)